# Linux usb wifi adapter not working - rtl88x2bu

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers

I recently got Linux installed on my laptop and noticed that I couldn't get wifi connection because "No wifi adapters found", and so I bought a USB wifi adapter online([here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QC3XQHW)). I looked online for drivers for the adapter and the common result I got was [this driver](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959) and so I followed the instructions written in the ReadMe for DKMS installation, but even after completing the last step, my laptop still wasn't able to detect the adapter.

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

I clicked the link for both the driver and the adapter and both were working fine. The full name of the adapter: XVZ USB WiFi Adapter, 600mbps Dual Band 2.4G/ 5G Wireless Adapter, Mini Wireless Network Card WiFi Dongle for Laptop/Desktop/PC, Support Windows10/8/8.1/7/Vista/XP/2000, Mac OS X 10.6-10.13

text link: [https://www.amazon.com/XVZ-Adapter-Wireless-Windows10-10-6-10-13/dp/B07QC3XQHW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QC3XQHW)

One thing I noticed was on the name it doesn't mention Linux, but in the product description, Linux was indeed listed as one of the supported OS.

There was a driver disk that came with the USB, but my laptop unfortunately doesn't have a disk drive. On the disk it had 8811CU/8812BU as version/type and when I tried `lsusb`, the product appears to be of Realtek. The closest driver I found online that's compatible with Linux is that one, but I'm not 100% sure it's the right one.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right driver? I use this with my WiFi dongle and it works great. Can you post the real link to the card (not some ad redirect) so I can see it?

Comment: nasdda / X and Y, please visit https://unix.stackexchange.com//help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts so that you can take ownership of your own question. Thank you!

Comment: Type us please the output of `$hwinfo --network` and `$lsusb`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a few comments that I read on the Amazon link, I think this link will be the best one for your adapter: https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.